# Writing the implementation for List<T> using IEnumerable<T> from scratch

Tags: c#, generics

Out of boredom I decided to write the implementation of List from scratch using IEnumerable.  I ran into a few issues that I honestly don't know how to solve:

1. How would you resize a generic array (T[]) when an index is nulled or set to default(T)?
2. Since you cannot null T, how do you overcome the numerical primitive problem with their values being 0 by default?
3. If nothing can be done regarding #2, how do you stop the GetEnumerator() method from yield returning 0 when utilizing a numerical data type?

Last but not least, what is the standard practice regarding downsizing an array?  I know for certain that one of the best solutions for upsizing is to increase the current length by a power of 2; if and when do you downsize?  Per Remove/RemoveAt or by the currently used length % 2?

Here's what I've done so far:

```
public class List<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    T[] list = new T[32];
    int current;

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        if (current + 1 > list.Length)
        {
            T[] temp = new T[list.Length * 2];
            Array.Copy(list, temp, list.Length);
            list = temp;
        }

        list[current] = item;
        current++;
    }

    public void Remove(T item)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
            if (list[i].Equals(item))
                list[i] = default(T);
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        list[index] = default(T);
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (T item in list)
            if (item != null && !item.Equals(default(T)))
                yield return item;
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (T item in list)
            if (item != null && !item.Equals(default(T)))
                yield return item;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _I know for certain that the best solution for upsizing is to increase the current length by a power of 2_. Do you really know for certain? Some implementations use `Count+Count/2`.

Comment: Instead of using `foreach (T item in list)`, do `for (int i = 0; i < current; i++) yield return list[i];`.

Comment: For your "nullability" problem, it happens because you would allow your array to have "holes". The standard `List<T>` solves the problem you're facing by not allowing holes. If you remove an object in the middle, they all get shifted one index.

Comment: Small thing to make your life easier, you can simplify the last method to `System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return GetEnumerator(); }`. Doing this makes the generic object version call the type specific version.

Comment: You might want to rethink your upsize algorithm. Using power of 2 would mean that if you wanted to upsize an array that current had 1000 elements, you would resize to 1 Million. I would opt for the @CoryNelson method which increases at a much slower rate.

Comment: @CoryNelson, I agree with your comment, can't assume a specific formula is good for all situations.  What implementations use `Count+Count/2`?  I could see rationalizing a larger increase but rarely see rationalizing a smaller one.  What's the specific use case?

Comment: @SamuelNeff: No matter what the multiplier is, the amortized cost of an insert is O(1); 100%-larger-when-full is convenient, but 50%-larger-when-full or 1%-larger-when-full also give O(1) cost. (Exercise: prove this.) The trade off is amount of wasted space vs number of expensive operations. When you grow by 100% when full you waste up to 100% space; when you grow by 1% when full you waste no more than 1% space. But you spend much more time resizing. That's the tradeoff to be struck.

Comment: @RCG: Re-implementing existing data structures from scratch is a great exercise. You might consider downloading the BCL source code to compare your solutions to the Microsoft solutions.

Comment: @EricLippert, I don't understand how the different growth calculations can all give O(1)?  Say we create a `List<int>()` with default initial capacity of 16 and then add 1000 items to it.  By default it will grow six times to get to 1024, each time copying the existing array.  If we instead used a 4x growth formula then we would only grow three times (16 to 64, 64 to 256, 256 to 1024) with far less copying.  Less time resizing, but likely more wasted space (as you said, trade off).  Say our calling code knows there's 1000 items and initializes the list to 1024 capacity, no copies, much faster?

Comment: @SamuelNeff: Obviously if you have more information about the maximum size then you can avoid the cost of reallocating.

Comment: @SamuelNeff: Do you understand why Add is O(1) amortized in a double-when-full list?  If not, start by proving why that is the case. (Hint: add up the total cost of those six array copies.) Once you've proved that, you can generalize your proof to show that increase-by-any-multiple-when-full is also O(1).

Comment: @EricLippert, thanks for the direction.  I'll play around with it with a co-worker and see how far I get.  Good timing, I'm on vacation.  Needed a good vacation project.  :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key problem you're running into is maintaining the internal array and what remove does.  `List<T>` does not support partial arrays internally.  That doesn't mean you can't, but doing so is far more complicated.  To exactly mimic `List<T>` you want to keep an array and a field for the number of elements in the array that are actually utilized (the list length, which is equal to or less than array length).

Add is easy, you add an element to the end like you did.

Remove is more complicated.  If you are removing an element from the end, set the end element to `default(T)` and change the list length.  If you are removing and element from the beginning or middle, then you need to shift the contents of the array and set the last one to `default(T)`.  The reason we set the last element to `default(T)` is to clear the reference, not so we can tell whether or not it's "in use".  We know if it's "in use" based on the position in the array and our stored list length.

Another key to implementation is the enumerator.  You want to loop through the first elements until you hit the list length.  Don't skip nulls.

This is not a complete implementation, but should be correct implementation of the methods you started.

btw, I would not agree with

> I know for certain that the best solution for upsizing is to increase the current length by a power of 2

This is the default behavior of `List<T>` but it's not the best solution in all situations.  That's exactly why `List<T>` allows you to specify a capacity.  If you're loading a list from a source and know how many items you're adding, then you can pre-initialize the capacity of the list to reduce the number of copies.  Similarly, if you're creating hundreds or thousands of lists that are larger than the default size or likely to be larger, it can be a benefit to memory utilization to pre-initialize the lists to be the same size.  That way the memory they allocate and free will be the same continuous blocks and can be more efficiently allocated and deallocated repeatedly.  For example, we have a reporting calculation engine that creates about 300,000 lists for each run, with many runs a second.  We know the lists are always a few hundred items each, so we pre-initialize them all to 1024 capacity.  This is more than most need, but since they're all the same length and they're created and disposed of very quickly, this makes memory reusage efficient.

```
    public class MyList<T> : IEnumerable<T>
    {
        T[] list = new T[32];
        int listLength;

        public void Add(T item)
        {
            if (listLength + 1 > list.Length)
            {
                T[] temp = new T[list.Length * 2];
                Array.Copy(list, temp, list.Length);
                list = temp;
            }

            list[listLength] = item;
            listLength++;
        }

        public void Remove(T item)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
                if (list[i].Equals(item))
                {
                    RemoveAt(i);
                    return;
                }
        }

        public void RemoveAt(int index)
        {
            if (index < 0 || index >= listLength)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("'index' must be between 0 and list length.");
            }

            if (index == listLength - 1)
            {
                list[index] = default(T);
                listLength = index;
                return;
            }

            // need to shift the list
            Array.Copy(list, index + 1, list, index, listLength - index + 1);
            listLength--;
            list[listLength] = default(T);
        }

        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {                
            for (int i = 0; i < listLength; i++)
            {
                yield return list[i];
            }
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Aside from one line being incorrect, that code is pretty much spot on in terms of what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

Well, for starters, your `Remove` and `RemoveAt` methods do not implement the same behavior as `List<T>`. `List<T>` will decrease in size by 1, whereas your `List` will remain constant in size. You should be shifting the values of higher index from the removed object to one lower index.

Also, `GetEnumerator` will iterate over all items in the array, regardless of what the value is.

I believe that will solve all of the issues you have. If someone adds a `default(T)` to the list, then a `default(T)` is what they will get back out again, regardless if `T` is an `int` and thus 0 or a class-type and thus `null`.

Finally, on downsizing: some growable array implementations rationalize that, if the array had ever gotten so big, then it is more likely than usual to get that big again. For that reason, they specifically avoid downsizing.

Comment: Great explanation.  I wish I could mark two posts as the correct answers.

Comment: (edited to add code formatting, which is *required* in order for angle brackets to appear, the rest is just for consistency)